# How to re-submit HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

**EDIT:** I made a dumb mistake. I was using some legacy code where `start` was greyed out after it was clicked. It's all fixed now. Lesson learned: parse through your code line by line if your file is small enough.

I have a form in html that calls a function titled `callStopwatch()` in javascript. Upon submitting the form for the first time, the function executes just fine. However, clicking the `submit` button another time doesn't do anything. Refreshing the page solves the problem, but I would like to be able to click on `submit` and return `callStopwatch()` multiple times without having to refresh. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<form id="options" action="" onsubmit="return callStopwatch()" method="post">

<fieldset>

<label> foo:

<input type="text" class="textForm" name="foo" size="2" /> foo1

</label>

<input type="submit" id="submit" class="button" alt="start" value="Start" />

<input type="reset" id="clear" class="button" alt="clear" value="Clear" />

<input type="button" id="reset" class="button" alt="reset" value="Reset" />

</fieldset>

</form>
```

JS:

```
var isRunning = false; // flag purposes

function callStopwatch() {
    var timer = document.getElementById('timer');
    var toggleBtn = document.getElementById('submit');
    var resetBtn = document.getElementById('reset');
    var clearBtn = document.getElementById('clear');

    watch = new Stopwatch(timer);
    watch.start();
    isRunning = true;

    resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        watch.stop();
        watch.reset();
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
    });

    clearBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        watch.stop();
        watch.reset();
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
    });
}

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true})
---more code here---
    .then(function(stream) {
            if(arbitrary_condition = true){
                watch.stop();
                isRunning = false;
            }
})
```

I know the above is a lot of code. I don't know where to look for the problem. The form should run my stopwatch again when I click `submit`, although it does not. Clicking `reset` then `start` behaves just fine, but I want to be able to click `start` without resetting.

Edit: I tried adding another eventlistener for the start button but it didn't work as expected. Maybe I did it wrong though.

Comment: Is it possible if we get more info, like where is the variable watch declared ?

Comment: ```watch``` is from a file called ```stopwatch.js```. It's initiated in the code up above with the line ```watch = new Stopwatch(timer)```. Does that help?

Comment: I think maybe you should add some code that checks if the stopwatch isn't already started. Since if you click on submit a second time you just create a new object without resetting the old one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is your problem, but this:

```
if(arbitrary_condition = true)
```

is almost certainly not what you want to be doing (= for assignment, == or === for comparison)

Comment: Thanks for the response. In my code, it's more like ```if(arbitrary_condition > threshold)```, if that helps.